# Can we turn this for loop into a more elegant Mathematica code?

Tags: performance-tuning, vector, permutation, coding-style

I am coding stuff manipulating indirection arrays and I have some code like:

```
createDupInvIndir[indirection_?VectorQ,duplicate_?VectorQ]:=
    Block[{n,dupInvIndir},
          n=Length[indirection];
          Assert[n==Length[duplicate]];
          dupInvIndir=ConstantArray[0,n];

          For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
             dupInvIndir[[indirection[[i]]]]=duplicate[[i]];
          ];

          Return[dupInvIndir];
    ];
```

We agree that this is not a good functional / Mathematica coding style. However, for the moment I have no idea to get an elegant/efficient way to remove the loop (using functions like Map, Scan...). Any suggestion/idea?

---

*to check it works*:

```
ind={3,5,4,2,1,6}
dup={1,2,2,3,3,3}
createDupInvIndir[ind,dup]
```

Output:

```
{3,3,1,2,2,3}
```

---

More context:

- `indirection`: is an indirection array got from `SortBy` function used with Range[1,n] to sort another array.
- `duplicate`: count different successive elements to detect duplicates

The array `dupInvIndir` that satisfies the relation:

```
dupInvIndir[[indirection[[i]]]]=duplicate[[i]]
```

is used to get the positions (taking into account the duplicate) of the sorted data without **explictely** reordering the data.

Here is a complete working example:

```
createDupInvIndir[indirection_?VectorQ,duplicate_?VectorQ]:=
    Block[{n,dupInvIndir},
          n=Length[indirection];
          Assert[n==Length[duplicate]];
          dupInvIndir=ConstantArray[0,n];
          For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
          dupInvIndir[[indirection[[i]]]]=duplicate[[i]];
          ];
          Return[dupInvIndir];
    ];

createDuplicate[data_List,indirection_?VectorQ]:=
Block[{dup},
      dup=Tally[Range[Length[indirection]],(data[[indirection[[#1]]]]==data[[indirection[[#2]]]])&];
      dup=Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray[#1,#2]&,{Range[Length[dup]],Part[dup,All,2]}]];
      Return[dup];
];

data={{3,4},{3,5},{1,2},{1,2},{2,3},{3,6},{5,6}} 
indirection=SortBy[Range[Length[data]],data[[#]]&]   (* {3,4,5,1,2,6,7} *)
duplicate=createDuplicate[data,indirection]          (* {1,1,2,3,4,5,6} *)
dupInvIndir=createDupInvIndir[indirection,duplicate] (* {3,4,1,1,2,5,6} <- Final result *)

(* same stuff with *explicit* sort: data components are moved *)
DeleteDuplicates[Sort[data]] (* {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{5,6}} *)
```

Take the first element of `dupInvIndir`, 3, it means that the first element of the (implicitely) sorted data array is `data[[3]]`, ( -> `{1,2}` ).
This can be compared to the explicit `DeleteDuplicate[Sort[data]]`

Comment: It would be somewhat easier with some context on what you actually try to achieve there...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher please holds on, I will add more context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, you try to apply a permutation given by list `indirection` to a vector `duplicate`.

Here are several ways to do it, each along with its timing:

```
n = 1000000;
indirection = RandomSample[Range[n], n];
duplicate = RandomInteger[{-n, n}, n];


First@RepeatedTiming[
  result0 = createDupInvIndir[indirection, duplicate];
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  result1 = ConstantArray[0, Length[duplicate]];
  result1[[indirection]] = duplicate;
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  result2 = 
    Normal@SparseArray[Partition[indirection, 1] -> duplicate,Length[duplicate]];
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  result3 = duplicate[[InversePermutation@indirection]];
  ]

result0 == result1 == result2 == result3
```

> 1.799
>
> 0.012
>
> 0.016
>
> 0.015
>
> True

This is another one of the many examples that highlights why `For` should not be used (in uncompiled code).

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, I already had the Normal @ SparseArray solution in mind but I eliminated it because I had the feeling it was not optimal concerning efficiency (a lot of manupilation, rules, array etc..). I did not know about the ToPackedArray package, thanks! (and yes indirection is a permutation of [1..Length[duplicate]])

Comment: The benchmark you just added confirms my feeling about perfs. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` is useful if you handle unpacked arrays that _could_ be packed (with pure machine integers or machine precision numbers (real or complex)). Of course, it is always better never to produce any unpacked arrays. ``Developer`PackedArrayQ`` lets you check whether an array is packed or not. I removed the use of ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` in my answer since `RandomSample` and `RandomInteger` are guaranteed to produce packed arrays (if the occurring integers are not too large).

Comment: `For` and the like can be quite useful. They are no substitute when alternatives exist that are vectorized though.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that replacing the `For` loop with a `Do` loop directly gives you a 25% speedup, without doing anything fancy. Also, it seems you've accidentally deleted the definition of `ToPack` from your answer...

Comment: @Lukas Lang Oh, I even meant to remove `ToPack` entirely. Thanks for pointing that out.